# How do I create a loop that takes keyboard input to print out row and column?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, input, java.util.scanner

My program will output a graphical representation of some rows and columns. It asks the users to input the number of rows and columns they want to see the figure for. For example if the user chooses 4 rows and 3 columns, it should print a figure (let's say it's made up of character X) which has 4 rows and 3 columns.

The final output will look like this:

```
X X X
X X X
X X X
X X X
```

***Now the problem is I can't set the logic in my for loop so that it makes the desired shape. I tried, but couldn't figure it out.***

This what I have done so far:

```
package banktransport;

import java.util.*;

public class BankTransport {

    static int NumOfRow;
    static int numOfColum;
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        showRowCol(NumOfRow, numOfColum);

    }

    public static void showRowCol(int NumOfRow, int numOfColum) {

        System.out.println("Enter row: ");
        NumOfRow = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Col: ");
        numOfColum = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Visual Representation: ");
        //print column and row 
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfColum; i++) {
            System.out.print(" X ");
           //System.out.println("");
            //for(int j=1; j<(NumOfRow-1);j++){
            // System.out.print(" Y ");

            //}
        }
        System.out.println("");

    }

}
```

Comment: you don't have any line breaks in your output, so all of your X's will show up as being on the same line.

Comment: Use another `for` inside the `for`, or outside of it. This outer `for` will control the number of rows and will call to `System.out.println`.

Comment: Luiggi Mendoza, I did, but it breaks line and doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: Use `System.out.println` only after you have printed the elements that compose the row.

Comment: Wrap another loop over the number of rows around the one you have now and you'll get the rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a loop like this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < numOfRow; i++ )
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < numOfColum; j++ )
    {
        System.out.print(" X ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Use `System.out.println` rather than `System.out.print("\n");`. This is because `println` will use break line based on the OS, while `\n` doesn't.

Comment: David Reeve, it doesn't make accurate row. the final output removes column

Comment: @someone try using `<=` instead of `<`

Comment: Doesn't this print one row too many, and one column too many?

Comment: @DavidWallace Previously, using `<`, it didn't output enough (see above comment by someone)

Comment: Well, I suspect she was mistaken.  Your code here prints `numOfRow + 1` rows and `numOfColum + 1` columns, which I don't think is what @someone wants.

Comment: Thanks, so cool David Reeve! it works. Let's pass few minutes to accept your answer.

Comment: @DavidWallace ok, I reverted it

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfRow; i++) {
    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
    for (int j = 0; j < numOfColumn; j++) {
        line.append("X ");
    }
    System.out.println(line.toString());
}
```

You can also use Apache Commons Lang [`StringUtils.repeat`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int)) method (which would prevent you from having a trailing space at the end of the line):

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfRow; i++) {
    System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat("X", " ", numOfColumn));
}
```

Comment: Good use of `StringBuilder` for efficiency.

Comment: I dislike trailing spaces at the end of lines.

Comment: It's probably faster to leave them, rather than introducing logic to check if it's the last 'X'.

Comment: But if you wanted to do that, it could be done with either `substring` or `deleteCharAt`

Comment: @laune You like it better with my second option? ;-)

Comment: Sure. Or change the String in the loop: `x = "X"/x = " "+x`